# I can only get one value out of ODReader

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

So I created an ODReader that executes a query where I get certain valeus out of a table.
However when I try to show this data in a mbox(just temporaraly) I can only show the first value.
And as soon as I try to get the second set of values it gives me this error  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

the code is as follows

```
     public void betaaldgroep()
     {
        List<int> groepsres = new List<int>();
        OracleParameter[] Betaald = new OracleParameter[10];//moet flexibel worden gemaakt

        OracleDataReader ODReader = DBConnection.Select("SELECT GROEPRESERVERING_ID,BETAALD FROM         GROEPRESERVERING ", Betaald);
        ODReader.Read();
        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ODReader["GROEPRESERVERING_ID"].ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(ODReader["BETAALD"].ToString());
            ODReader.NextResult();

        }



    }
```

Now my qeuistion is how can I show every set of valeus instead of just the first one?

Comment: what do you do if you return more than 2 records I would suggest changing the for loop to a While Loop also since you are in the same loop for the first iteration for example I would also implement the `string.Join()` and you could even store the values in a List<string> and implement `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", YourList));`

Answer (score 0):

`ODReader.NextResult();` would return you the next "result set" from your query. You have just a single `SELECT` statement in your query so you will end up with one result set. Since there is no second result set, when you try to access `ODReader["GROEPRESERVERING_ID"].ToString()` you get a null reference exception.

What you should look for is to get the next row from your result set. Use

`ODReader.Read();` to iterate to the next result set. If you want to only restrict yourself to reading two rows from the result set use:

```
OracleDataReader ODReader = DBConnection.Select("SELECT GROEPRESERVERING_ID,BETAALD FROM         GROEPRESERVERING ", Betaald);
int counter = 0;
while (ODReader.Read() && counter < 2)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ODReader["GROEPRESERVERING_ID"].ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(ODReader["BETAALD"].ToString());
    counter++;
}
```